# How to trigger an Azure Policy from an Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-policy, azure-runbook, azure-billing

How can we trigger an Azure Policy from an Azure Runbook? example - to may be stop provisioning of resources in a subscription temporarily.
I have basically created an Budget Action Group to an Azure Runbook via Webhook. This works successfully, but need to also test Azure Policy trigger via a Runbook if the Budget/Action Group gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure policy definitions and assignments exist. A policy definition is just that, it defines what a policy would do if it were to be *assigned* to a certain scope in a Policy assignment.

So you could create the policy definition for blocking resource creation and first test it at the scope of a testing resourcegroup. When everything works as expected you can create simple powershell commands in your runbook to create the assignment at the scope needed when the runbook is triggered. You could also automate the removal of the policy assignment.

PowerShell commands are: `New-AzPolicyAssignment` and `Remove-AzPolicyAssignment`.

Further documentation on assigning policies can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-powershell)

Comment: Thank you so much @roderick
This looks like what I wanted, will try to test this asap. :)